# Set of tuples in Isabelle

Tags: set, tuples, definition, isabelle

Im trying to write in a definition which takes a term and a set of tuples as argument but I don't know how to display the set of tuples

```
theory fullbb
imports 
Main

begin 
typedecl NAME
typedecl ADDRESS

locale addresbook
begin

definition address :: "NAME set ⇒ (NAME * ADDRESS) set ⇒ bool"
where 
"address name addresses  = (name = dom (addresses))"
end
```

The error message I get with this is

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_set" and "_=>_"    
Type error in application: incompatible operand type
Operator: dom :: (??'a => ??'b option) => ??'a set
Operand: addresses :: (NAME x ADDRESS) set
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `address` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `dom` returns the domain of a map, which is modeled in HOL as a function `'a => 'b option`. For a relation (i.e., a set of tuples), the appropriate function is called `Domain`. So just use  `Domain` instead of `dom` in your definition and it should type-check as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to CNTL-click on pertinent functions to see what they do, and see what their type signature is.

For `dom`, it takes me to [line 40 of Map.thy](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/5ae2a2e74c93/src/HOL/Map.thy#l40):

```
definition
  dom :: "('a ~=> 'b) => 'a set" where
  "dom m = {a. m a ~= None}"
```

It's looking like you're not dealing with tuples. There is this type synonym at [line 13](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/5ae2a2e74c93/src/HOL/Map.thy#l13):

```
type_synonym ('a,'b) "map" = "'a => 'b option" (infixr "~=>" 0)
```

The `locale` is not important here. I change the tuple syntax to this:

```
definition address :: "NAME set => (NAME ~=> ADDRESS) set => bool"
where 
  "address name addresses = (name = dom (addresses))"
```

I still get a type error. It's because `dom` needs type `(NAME ~=> ADDRESS)`.

```
definition address :: "NAME set => (NAME ~=> ADDRESS) => bool" 
where 
  "address name addresses = (name = dom (addresses))"
```

So, `dom` is not what you thought it was.